# Gradle or Groovy - how to convert URL to file?

Tags: gradle, groovy

In Gradle I have a file stored on the Internet that I would like to access. But I can't figure out how to convert a `URL` to a `File` in Gradle.  I need the url to be converted to a file so I can pass it to tasks as a file. Here is what I have so far:

```
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
      String file = new URL('http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.json').file
    }
}
```

this is definetly not what i want. The file variable ends up being: `demos/samples/sample.json` so it looks like it's just taking the path from the url itself.

I need the actual `sample.json`  to be stored in a `File` object. I would also prefer if possible to not have to write the file to local storage where it is accessible to other people as its a secure file.

Comment: Can you get away with just the contents of the file? `String fileContent =   new URL('http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.json').text`

Comment: no. actually that is just a sample. what i am trying to really pull down is a private keystore.  so i definetly need the file or the bytes.

Comment: Maybe `byte[] fileContent = new URL('http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.json').bytes` then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way to do this:

```
def fileLocation = 'file://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.json'
def fileURL = new URL(fileLocation)
def remoteFile = new File(fileURL.toURI())
```

See: [File(URI uri)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI))

Replace `fileLocation` with valid value for your task.

Answer (score 1):

As of May 4, 2018, Gradle 4.8 RC1 or later, if you are facing this problem using checkstyle, you can use

```
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "8.13"
    config project.resources.text.fromUri("${someUrl}/checkstyle.xml")
}
```

See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2663